# Google Play Services 4.3 isn't recognized by Android Studio 0.5.3

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I recently updated to use Google Play Services 4.3.+

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.+'
    ...
}
```

Android Studio 0.5.3 is now complaining for all things related (Google Maps, Location related classes, etc). I've tried restarting Android Studio, re-importing my project after deleting the .iml and .idea folder. I also tried removing the gradle cache `gradle-1.10-all` from my .gradle folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, updating my gradle wrapper to 1.11 fixed the issue.

The properties file is location at `project_root > gradle > wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties`

I changed

`distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip`

to

`distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip`

and now everything is recognized correctly.